# Can you deliver it [when,after] it [is | will be] assembled?

Tags: questions, subordinate-clauses, time-reference

Right now we are assembling a device. I am asking another person if he is can deliver it [after/when] we finish. What question construction is the most correct?

1. Can you deliver it after it is assembled?
2. Can you deliver it after it will be assembled?
3. Can you deliver it when it will be assembled?
4. Can you deliver it when it is assembled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions 2 and 3 are not idiomatic, but 1 and 4 are fine.

This website agrees, and has a very pretty picture on it:
[Jakub Marian "will after when"](https://jakubmarian.com/will-after-when-in-english/)
"We never use the future tense in time clauses (introduced by phrases like “after”, “as soon as”, “before”, etc.) in English."